# Building a list of functions that return strings

Tags: r

Could someone please explain why the following snippet behaves as it does?

```
l <- list()
AddFn <- function(str) { l[[length(l) + 1]] <<- function() { return(str) }}
AddFn("hello")
AddFn("there")
l[[1]]()  # Returns "hello" as expected
l[[2]]()  # Returns "there" as expected
for (letter in letters) AddFn(letter)
l[[3]]()  # Returns "z"
```

I expected `l[[3]]()` to return "a".  What am I missing?  What exactly does my AddFn function do?

Thank you in advance,

Adrian

Comment: +1 for writing a function that makes my brain hurt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lazy evaluation often results in the last evaluation in a loop getting returned. Try this instead:

```
AddFn <- function(str) { force(str); l[[length(l) + 1]] <<- function() { return(str) }}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a nasty one. The `str` argument is set to a promise that says to return `letter`, but it isn't actually evaluated until called via `l[[3]]()`. So the value *at that point* is used!

If you change the last part to:

```
for (letter in letters) AddFn(letter)
letter="foo" 
l[[3]]()  # Returns "foo"
```

...You'll see it more clearly.
...So do what @DWin suggests and call `force` first.

Comment: I think the use of the loop complicates things.  Something like `a<-"test"; AddFn(a); a <- "haha it changed"; l[[3]]()` gets the point across too.

Comment: @Dason, an explanation of your correct comment about the loop playing a large role (from `?"for"`): `for` "sets `var` (in this case `letter`) to the last used element of `seq` (in this case `letters`, the last element of which is `z`)".